# Correcting invalid XML

Tags: xml, validation, format

I have this XML which is invalid. Im trying to correct this but unable to get whats wrong here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:call><sessionId xsi:type="xsd:string">e64b8a49ca92df53bd8718b0aab58d27</sessionId>
<resourcePath xsi:type="xsd:string">customapi_api.customerlogin</resourcePath>
<args xsi:type="ns2:Map">
<item><key xsi:type="xsd:string">sendData</key>
      <value xsi:type="ns2:Map">

      <item><key xsi:type="xsd:string">password</key><value xsi:type="xsd:string">example@123</value></item>
      <item><key xsi:type="xsd:string">email</key><value xsi:type="xsd:string">admin@example.com</value></item></value>
</item>
</args>
</ns1:call>
</SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>","response_env":"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

What is wrong here ?

Comment: What makes you think it is invalid? Has some tool reported an error message? Maybe including that message in the question might help. (Or trying a different tool, maybe one dedicated to finding problems in XML)

Comment: There are two XMLS in that input. That would make it not valid as one XML